# Efficient Way to get the number of File Handles Open By a Process in Go?

Tags: linux, go

I have a monitoring agent called scollector that is using more cpu on our loadbalancer. Perf says the CPU is mostly due to `__d_lookup`. One of the things I monitor is the number of open file handles - I do this via the following code:

```
    fds, e := ioutil.ReadDir("/proc/" + pid + "/fd")
    if e != nil {
        w.Remove(pid)
        continue
    }
    ...
    Add(md, "linux.proc.num_fds", len(fds), tags, metadata.Gauge, metadata.Files, descLinuxProcFd)
```

When I strace the process, I see it calling `lstat` on every file in the `/fd` directory (which is going to be a lot for our active load balancer (at least .5 million fds) - so I hypothesizing that this is the source of the high dentry cache cpu usage for the process.

Anyone have a suggestion on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble with `ioutil.Readdir` is that it does `file.Readdir` which says that it does an `lstat` for every file.

It seems [`Readdirnames`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames) doesn't do this, returning only the names. And since you only want the count, that should be enough.

Comment: Here is the unix implementation of readdirnames: golang.org/src/os/dir_unix.go

Comment: Readdir also sorts, that might be a lot of the CPU. I did notice that `/* Open file table structure */
struct files_struct {
 int count;
 fd_set close_on_exec;
 fd_set open_fds;
 struct file * fd[NR_OPEN];
}` is part of task_struct in linux. I wonder if I can get that count via syscall somehow...

Comment: @KyleBrandt I wondered about that too. If it would be anywhere I would expect it to be in `stat`.